# How do I resolve Promisse.all

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, es6-promise

I have an array of promises that looks like this:

```
const content = await getData() //gets data from API
    const drinkURL =  content.drinks.map( item => "lookup.php?i=" + item.idDrink) // gets element in the API end-point
    const getInfo = async() => {
        let allPromises = Promise.all(drinkURL.map(item => getData(item)))  
        allPromises.catch(e => console.log(e)) // Trying to catch any errors here, but can't.
        return allPromises    
    }
```

I want to add a catch statement in case any of the promises can not resolve.
I have tried writing it inside the `getInfo` function, and after the `.then()` inside the next snippet.

```
const view = `
        <div class="Drink-card">
            <a href="/">Home</a>
            ${await getInfo()
                .then(ele => ele.map(item => item.drinks.map( drink => `
            <article class="Drink-main">
                <img src="${drink.strDrinkThumb}" alt="${drink.strDrink}">
                <h2>${drink.strDrink}</h2>
            </article>
`)).join("")).catch(e => console.log(e))//Does not work in here either}
```

I have tried a bunch of ways but can't come up with a working result.

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure I’m following. Are you expecting there’s an error but it’s not being caught? What’s happening instead? Would it be possible to update your example to be complete (might use setTimeout)?

Comment: Sorry... I misread your code. `await` can only be used in `async function`s.

Comment: @stealththeninja the API end-point will not return a result given an unexistent URL. So I am trying to catch whenever the end-point does not exist and render a 404 message. I am updating the question with a link to the repo, I hope that makes it easier to see what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Thanks but it’s actually a great skill to learn—creating small, complete examples. Often in the process of preparing to explain my problem I see the issue—and if not, I’ve simplified it to make it easier for us to talk about.

Comment: `allPromises.catch(e => console.log(e))` is a bit weird since you just log the error there, but still have `getInfo` return the potentially rejected promise. `getInfo().then(ele => …).catch(e => console.log(e))//Does not work in here either` should definitely work. Please tell us what happens in that solution when a `getData()` errors.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `await` keyword (1) combines with `catch` inside of each promise (2) as the following simple sample :

[image]

**Full code sample below:**

```
function getData(object){
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        if(object.value === "3") 
            throw new Error("Whoops!") 
        else 
            resolve(object.value);
    });
}

var drinkURLs = [{ value: "1" }, { value: "2" }, { value: "3" }];
var getInfo = async() => {
    var promises =  drinkURLs.map(item => getData(item));
    var results = await Promise.all(promises.map(p => p.catch(e => e)));
    var inValidResults = results.filter(result => (result instanceof Error));
    var validResults = results.filter(result => !(result instanceof Error));
    console.log({inValidResults, validResults}); 

    return validResults;    
}

await getInfo();
```

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work for my case, thanks for taking the time

Comment: Oh no, I saw that you mark as resolved, then you changed to unmark? What happened?

Comment: It made a lot of sense, but I have the same issue after applying it. Thanks again!

Comment: Really? Show us your issue here. Thanks.

Comment: The data I was getting was not an array, and that's why it was not working. Had to do a little sanitizing. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Promise.allSettled()` function.

The `Promise.allSettled()` method returns a promise that resolves after all of the given promises have either fulfilled or rejected, with an array of objects that each describes the outcome of each promise while `Promise.all` rejects immediately upon any of the input promises rejecting or non-promises throwing an error, and will reject with this first rejection message / error.